# Can't find javac Error while Deploying Play Application

Tags: playframework, sbt, javac, playframework-2.6

So this question has been asked before, but following everything, setting the path and moving it to the top, and everything else I can't get it to work.

Here's the full error https://hastebin.com/qezelugaba.rb

In summary, for some reason SBT thinks that javac is located within the project's working directory and not where the environment path variable has it set.

I have no clue how/where to fix this.

I am/was following this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying on deploying my app, following the `dist` command.

To follow up, I have the path to my JDK in the Environment variables like so
[Environment Variable Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNKSG.png)
and yes I do have JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was initially following this video tutorial series on youtube, and he told us to delete a bunch of files from within the application directory, one of these files must have contained what was needed, and downloading a fresh build and adding all the files that didn't exist in the working directory seemed to fix the error.

If you have a similar error just go to the play framework site and download a starter project to copy some files.
https://www.playframework.com/download